# python type documentation list of Foobar

Tags: python-2.7, documentation, pycharm, type-hinting

I have a class like this

```
class Foobar(object):
    def add_bazzes(self, new_bazzes):
        # type (list(Baz)) -> object
        for new_baz in new_bazzes:
            self.__do_something__(new_baz)
```

Now, my IDE is not capable to infer, that `new_bazzes` is a list of type `Baz`. Is there a way how to add some type documentation to the method?

pycharm does auto-suggest

```
# type (object) -> object
```

but when filling it with

```
# type (list(Baz)) -> object
```

it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In intellij pycharm, the following docstring help:

```
class Foobar(object):
    def add_bazzes(self, new_bazzes):
        """
        @type new_bazzes: list[Baz]
        """
        for new_baz in new_bazzes:
            self.__do_something__(new_baz)
```